# RequireJS : Uncaught Error - Script Error for a module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Would like to share this issue I recently debugged.
I was getting this error in Chrome console for a particular page.
[image]
Debugged the script - No error, actually the script is working correctly in some other modules and components.

"officeUtilities" script is not loading due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't fix it in the active session of browser, following worked for me. 
- Opening page in Chrome incognito mode and other browsers (Firefox, Edge, IE).

I think it is caching issue. I deleted all browser cached images and files , but that didn't work. I didn't tried to delete all history, that will end up logging out of multiple sites.

Since I found a alternative way to test the page, I'm Okay with it.